# Simple example to illustrate writing an abstraction layer in C++

Tags: c++

I have just rudimentary knowledge in C++. I am trying to implement Hardware Abstraction Layer(HAL) in C++. Say suppose I want to implement this class called Data. Based on the platform the data can be sent wired or wireless.

```
class Data() {

public Data() {

//create random data

}

public sendData() {

// send data

}

public platform_action1() {

// do some platform specific action
}
```

}

```
// My HAL
    int HAL() {

    Data myData;

    myData.platform_action1();
    myData.sendData();

    return 0;
    }
```

Now if I have two platforms wired and wireless, how do I extend this class and organize my files so that `HAL()` is unchanged.

Also I do not want dynamic binding i.e using keyword 'virtual'.
In my case the platform is known at compile time.

// I DO NOT want to do this :) ...

```
int HAL() {
Data* data = new WiredData();
data.sendData();

data = new WirelessData();

data.sendData();

}
```

In my case the platform is known at compile time.

Coming from C world this is as simple task as filling in the platform specific function pointers.

Take for example 'thread' class in Boost C++ API. The class automatically spawns threads by calling either Windows thread API or Linux thread API based on the platform. This way my HAL is truly platform independent.

- thanks
  Kris

Comment: You should try something and if it doesn't work, ask why.  Don't just ask people to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a design question than an actual C++ question, but the term you are looking for is `polymorphism`. You can take your `Data` class and create two classes that inherit from it `WiredData` and `WirelessData, this would enable you to do something like this:

```
Data data1 = new WiredData();
Data data2 = new WirelessData();

data1.sendData();
data2.sendData();
```

polymorphism comes into play when you call `sendData()` on the data1 and data2 objects, the compiler will call the `sendData()` method for each specific subtype even though they are declared to be of type `Data`

Comment: Hunter, I really do not want to do this:

Data data1 = new WiredData();
Data data2 = new WirelessData();

I just want data connection to be figured out during the sendData() call. 
Take for example 'thread' class in Boost C++ API. The class automatically spawns threads by calling either Windows thread API or Linux thread API based on the platform. This way my HAL is truly platform independent.

Answer (score 1):

> Coming from C world this is as simple task as filling in the platform specific function pointers.

It's pretty much the same in C++.  You can make the Data class's sendData() function `virtual` (prefix the `virtual` keyword to the signature), then derive Wired and Wireless implementation classes that specifies appropriate `sendData()` functionality.  You then have some kind of if statement where you decide which one to use, and keep a `Data*` variable to the `Wired` or `Wireless` object as needed... when you call `pointer->sendData()`, it will invoke the corresponding implementation.  This is all really basic - you should do a couple introductory C++ tutorials online, or grab a book.  There are other stackoverflow questions listing recommended training material.

Edit: an outline as per the request in your comment below.

```
class Wrapper
{
    Data* p_;
  public:
    void sendData()
    {
        if (not p_)
            p_ = ... ? new Wired() : new Wireless();
        p_->sendData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tony, Thanks for the reply. Thought of doing the same thing as you mentioned. But in the main() call I do not want to know if I have Wired or Wireless platform underneath. Can pointer->sendData() pick the platform at later stage?

Comment: The proper (most derived) version of a `virtual` function is resolved at run-time, so you don't need to know in `main` what the actual type is.  This is a core language feature; you should find a book or tutorial as Tony suggests.

Comment: Please see the post to Hunter's reply.

Comment: @user1715819: sure - you can move the decision of Wires vs. Wireless into a wrapper class, so it chooses which one to instantiate at a convenient time.  Doing this, you need four classes: the wrapper used directly by `main()`, the two implementations, and a base class with virtual functions describing their shared API.

Comment: Tony ... Can you please provide me outline of the code for wrapper. Is this wrapper a macro? Any idea how 'thread' class in Boost C++ is implemented?

Comment: And how thread's implemented is a separate question - please post it as such, though it's vague enough that if I was moderating I'd seriously consider closing it.  If you look at it yourself, summarise what you've found and ask specific questions the question will be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Tony.  Is there any design pattern you are aware of doing this? I tried to go over layer pattern & decorator pattern. But seems they are not achieving what I want.

Comment: @user1715819: it's a State pattern.

Comment: Thanks Tony.  Is there any design pattern you are aware of doing this? I tried to go over layer pattern & decorator pattern. But seems they are not achieving what I want. Here is some more concrete information about my evolving requirement. 1. Application data sent via IPC to HAL. 2. HAL operations (1. parse the data 2. Reformat data 3. Send Data based on the attached device either Wired or Wireless.) The last step is platform dependent. This used to be done by filling in platform dependent function pointer. I want to do this now using C++.

Comment: @user1715819: as above, the design pattern's called the "State pattern". More generally, I suggest you continue to use function pointers as you'd do in C. It'll be easier for you to learn C++ by starting using std::map, std::vector, std::string, some algos, maybe a template or two where you found yourself going to write very-similar functions for two or more types, and gradually learning to use other features where the C++ mechanisms are clumsy; no need to complicate things further by choosing C++ mechanisms that aren't clearly simpler for you anyway.

Comment: Hi Tony, Can you please my post below? Is this one way of doing this i.e PIMPL pattern?

Comment: @user1715819: I'll comment on that answer.

Comment: Tony ... Please see my new comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the definitions for the members that change into files called :-

`Data_Windows.cpp` and `Data_Unix.cpp` (for example) and then use your build system to only include the relevent file in your build on that platform? Or am I missing something here...?

Answer (score 0):

```
Can we do this using PIMPL(Private Implementation) approach? This is what I am thinking ...

// In Data.h

class PlatformDataProcess;                    // forward declaration of Pimpl
 
class Data
{
public:
   Data (const IPC& ipc); // process IPC
   ~Data();
 
   Data( const Data &rhs );   // undefined for simplicity
   Data& operator=( Data );
 
   void  process_ipc();
 
private:
   PlatformDataProcess *pimpl_;              // the Pimpl
};

// In Wired.cpp

#include "Data.h"
 
class PlatformDataProcess
{
public:
   void SendData()  {// send data on wired}
 
};


// In Data.cpp
 
Data::Data()  :  pimpl_( new PlatformDataProcess() )
{
}
 
Data::~Data()
{
   delete  pimpl_;
}
 
void   Data::SendData()
{
   pimpl_->SendData();      // do some private work   
}

int HAL() {

  // receive IPC

  Data* data = new Data(ipc);
  data->SendData();

}

So all the user needs to do is supply the platform specific file like wired.cpp .
```

Comment: How does your initialisation of pimpl_ (`pimpl_( new PlatformDataProcess() )`) relate to the choice of Wired versus Wireless? For an OO solution, somewhere that choice needs to be made, and `new` used for either Wired or Wireless. When you add that factor in, it becomes a State pattern. pImpl has similarities, but the intension is not to vary the implementation at runtime so much as hide the implementation (and in C++ to avoid the need to recompile when private members are added/removed/changed in the client-visible class/header).

Comment: Tony, Actually I chose bad example i.e wired and wireless. In my case either the board has either data chip1 or chip2. Compile time definition of PlatformDataProcess is fine as I do not want to include code for all the chips in my build.